# Function shift() doesn't work inside loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to manipulate an array inside a for loop, where I want to add an item to the end of the array and delete an element at the beginning of the array, like this:

```
var internal = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    internal[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 37);

    internal.shift();
    console.log(internal.length);
}
```

The problem is that it looks like shift() doesn't work inside the loop, in fact, no element is deleted from the array!

Is there a solution?

Here [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lughino/JE8wg/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reduces by one every time, but you are growing it every time by accessing it with the array index accessing. Instead of

```
internal[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 37);
```

use

```
internal.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 37));
```

For example,

```
var internal = [];
internal[3] = "thefourtheye";
console.log(internal);
```

**Output**

```
[ , , , 'thefourtheye' ]
```

It made space for the first three elements and added the element at the index specified. So, it will keep the array growing.

**Note:** Use `[]` to create a new array, instead of `new Array()`

Answer (score 1):

because you are using a hard coded index, try

```
var internal = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    internal.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 37));

    internal.shift();
    console.log(internal.length);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s94WQ/)

---

```
//test
var arr = [];
arr[50] = 1;
console.log('arr.length', arr.length);
```

will print `51` not `1`